# Pygame, Tkinter or something else for TUI and responding to keyboard input?

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, pygame, tui

I'm quite new to programming and trying to write a fairly simple program that records the times in between different keyboard button presses (a bit like multiple reaction time tests) and prints these times on screen in an array, then terminates and saves the array after a certain period of time is up.

I've already written most of the program in pygame after giving up on Tkinter because it seemed to be the best thing for responding to keyboard input in real time. However, now that I'm wanting the text to scroll automatically once the screen fills up, add more columns to the array, and export to Excel, I'm starting to wonder whether I'd be better off with a module more suited to text handling.

Can anyone advise me on whether I'm making a mistake attempting this in pygame and whether responding immediately to multiple keyboard inputs in Tkinter is possible? I can provide more detail if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "responding immediately to multiple keyboard inputs"? Do you mean "multiple" as in pressing several keys simultaneously, or simply typing fast? What do you mean "real time" -- tkinter can respond to events within milliseconds, is that not fast enough?

Comment: No, I just mean a range of inputs without pressing enter. I want to calculate the time between pressing for example 'a' and then 'b'. When I looked up how to do this in tkinter I couldn't find anything and thought that I would need to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Using Tkinter, you can bind to `<Any-KeyPress>`. The function that is called is passed an event object that has a timestamp. You can use that to compute the time between events.

Here's a quick example that shows how to display the time between keypresses. You can of course add your own logic to count and track and display however you want.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.last_event = None
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="word")

        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.text.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", self.on_key_release)

    def on_key_release(self, event):
        if self.last_event is not None:
            delta = event.time - self.last_event.time
            self.label.configure(text="time since last event: %s ms" % delta)
        self.last_event = event

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, this will be very helpful if I decide to switch to Tkinter.